# ASP.NET: How can I use a listener defined on Web.Config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, webforms, system.diagnostics

I'm developing an ASP.NET WebForm application with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and C#.

I've defined the following listener on Web.Config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\Logs\logWeb.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

How can redirect output from OutPut Window to this listener? All sentences like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("IntegratedManaged: ResolveCulture");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IntegratedManaged: ResolveCulture");
```

are shown on output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Now, Web.Config look like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
        <listeners>
            <remove name="Default" />
            <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\Logs\logWeb.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

It is necessary to remove Default listener.

Answer (score 0):

A good article for it is [here](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020910.htm)

If you want to listen to the WMI events of asp.net application refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178713.aspx)